# RedHat multiple NICs routing issue

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a red hat 6.3 machine with 2 physical nics installed. I also have a virtual adapter on eth0 as well.

eth1 is 10.3.80.215 - this is the network that has infrastructure servers for vmware (vcenter,etc)

eth0 is 10.231.1.2 which is the http connection for the my vcloud director server.

eth0:0 is 10.231.1.3 which is the console proxy connection.

I can ping any of the ips from anywhere except I can not ping the 10.231 addresses from any machines on the 10.3.80 subnet .

Any ideas of how to get this to work?

here is the ifconfig and the route table.

## ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:E3:CD:29  
          inet addr:10.231.1.2  Bcast:10.231.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::xxx:xxxx:fee3:cd29/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:710145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:636043 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:146272731 (139.4 MiB)  TX bytes:340604630 (324.8 MiB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:E3:CD:29  
          inet addr:10.231.1.3  Bcast:10.231.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:E3:CD:33  
          inet addr:10.3.80.215  Bcast:10.3.80.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::xx:xxxx:fee3:cd33/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26643771 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6416677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4879371482 (4.5 GiB)  TX bytes:1349011239 (1.2 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:121636 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121636 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12040727 (11.4 MiB)  TX bytes:12040727 (11.4 MiB)
```

## route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.231.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.3.80.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
default         10.231.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Are you trying to use this machine to route the traffic between the different subnets?  If so, we will need to see the output of `iptables -nvL --line-numbers` and `iptables -nvL --line-numbers -t nat`.

Comment: I am not trying to route using it really, that is the way that vmware recommended i set it up so all backend traffic goes over the .80 NIC and the front end stuff goes over the 10.231.1.2 NIC.

Comment: from one of the clients in the 10.3.80 network run tracepath 10.231.1.3 and show us the output

Comment: iptables -nvL --line-numbers
        Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
        num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source              destination         

        Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
        num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source             destination         

        Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
        num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source              destination

Comment: # iptables -nvL --line-numbers -t nat
        Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
        num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

        Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
        num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

        Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
        num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: i dont know what tracepath is..

Comment: How are the return packets supposed to get to their destination? Do machines on the 10.3.80 subnet have a route to the 10.231 subnet? If not, the replies won't get back. Troubleshoot. Do the pings go out? Are they received? Are replies sent? Where do they go?

Comment: from the linux box I can ping anything - i have no issues.  from any other subnet in the network I can ping the 10.231.1.2 and .3 addresses as well as the 10.3.80 address.  however, from any machine on the .80 subnet, i can ping the .80 address and it returns, but if I ping the 10.231.1.2 and .3, they do not return.  I do not have a static route on my laptop that is for the 10.231, it would go thru the default (0.0.0.0)  I added one to see routing to my default gateway (10.3.80.1) and same thing - just wont respond.  I hope thats clearer.

Comment: @Drew: Does the default gateway know how to get packets to 10.231.1.x?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have reverse path filtering enabled. Check `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter` and make sure it is 0 (disabled) (or 2, loose) for eth0 and eth1. The default has changed from RHEL5 to RHEL6. See http://blog.yibi.org/2012/01/05/reverse-path-filtering-in-rhel-6

Comment: I changed the value of rp_filter to a 2 and it worked!!!!  fantastic answer, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You may have to have forwarding on.  `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, if it is 0, the server isn't forwarding packets between interfaces.  You can set it with `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

Or you can immediately change the value by running:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward.
```

See if that does the trick.

Comment: I changed the IP_Forward value from 0 to 1.  I restarted the linux server, but still cannot ping from the .80 where in the sysctl.conf file would I add that line?

Comment: nevermind, sorry I see it, I will make the change now

Comment: I made the change o the sysctl.conf file, and rebooted.  IP_forward shows as a 1 now but I can still not ping or connect from the .80 subnet machines

Comment: @Drew you've been playing with Microsoft servers too long - the 'echo' method effects changes immediate, the sysctl.conf implements the changes at the next reboot - you don't need to reboot your server to enable the change. Do the connecting clients have a route to 10.231.* via 10.3.80.215 ?

Comment: my laptop currently is set with 10.3.80.247.  I can ping any IP on the network and get a response except for the 10.231.1.2 and .3 addresses.  clients do not need to route thru the .80 NIC to get to the .231 subnet.  it just needs to know how to send back traffic.

Comment: and yes, far too long with microsoft.....

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the the reverse path filtering introduced in redhat 6 & above. You might want to check the following post for resolution:

- http://www.virtualizationteam.com/virtualization-vmware/vcloud-director/how-to-get-redhat-6-2-linux-second-nic-to-ping.html